# RuntimeError: Failed to process string with tex because latex could not be found in Windows PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Colleagues, I apologize for such an already disassembled question, but other same posts not help me find the solutuion... I use PyCharm at the Windows 10.

For example I have a code for plot graph with Latex labels strings

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import ticker
from matplotlib import rc

rc('text', usetex=True)


# def fct(x):
#     if -2 <= x < -1:
#         y = 1.0
#     elif -1 <= x < 0:
#         y = -1.0
#     elif 0 <= x < 0.5:
#         y = 2.0
#     elif 0.5 <= x < 1:
#         y = -2
#     else:
#         y = 0
#     return y


def phi_k_l1(x):
    if -2 <= x < -1:
        y = 1
    else:
        y = 0
    return y


def phi_k_l2(x):
    if -1 <= x < 0:
        y = -1
    else:
        y = 0
    return y


def phi_k_l3(x):
    if 0 <= x < 1 / 2:
        y = 1.4142 * 1.4142
    else:
        y = 0
    return y


def phi_k_l4(x):
    if 1 / 2 <= x < 1:
        y = 1.4142 * -1.4142
    else:
        y = 0
    return y


def bl(x):
    if -2 <= x < 1:
        y = 0
    else:
        y = 0
    return y


def bl1(x):
    if -7 <= x < -2:
        y = 0
    else:
        y = 0
    return y


x = np.arange(-3, 2, 0.001)
xx = np.arange(0.49, 5.49, 0.001)
# yf = [fct(i) for i in x]
yp1 = [phi_k_l1(i) for i in x]
yp2 = [phi_k_l2(i) for i in x]
yp3 = [phi_k_l3(i) for i in x]
yp4 = [phi_k_l4(i) for i in xx]
x1 = np.arange(-2, 1, 0.002)
xx1 = np.arange(-5, -2, 0.002)
yp5 = [bl(i) for i in x1]
yp6 = [bl1(i) for i in xx1]
# yd = [fct(i) - phi_k_l(i) for i in x]


plt.style.use('science')  
sns.set(font_scale=2)
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14, 12))
tick_spacing = 0.5
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(tick_spacing))
ax.set_title(r"\textbf{$f(x)=\varphi_{0}(x-2)+(-1)\varphi_{0}(x-1)+\sqrt{2}\varphi_{1}(x)+(-\sqrt{2})\varphi_{1}(x+1)$}",
             pad=20)
ax.set_ylabel('$\\varphi(x)$', rotation='vertical')
ax.set_xlabel('$x$', labelpad=5)
ax.set_ylabel(ax.get_ylabel(), rotation=0, ha='right')
g1 = sns.lineplot(x=x, y=yp1, color='red', linestyle='-', linewidth=1, label='$\\varphi_{0}(x-2)$')
g1.set(xlim=(-2.5, -1))
sns.lineplot(x=x, y=yp2, color='blue', linestyle='-', linewidth=1, label='$(-1)\\varphi_{0}(x-1)$')
g2 = sns.lineplot(x=x, y=yp3, color='darkgreen', linestyle='-', linewidth=1, label='$\\sqrt{2}\\varphi_{1}(x)$')
g2.set(xlim=(0, 0.5))
sns.lineplot(x=xx, y=yp4, color='purple', linestyle='-', linewidth=1, label='$-\\sqrt{2}\\varphi_{1}(x+1)$')
sns.lineplot(x=x1, y=yp5, color='lightgrey', linestyle='-', linewidth=1.1)
sns.lineplot(x=xx1, y=yp6, color='red', linestyle='-', linewidth=1)
# sns.lineplot(x=x, y=yd, color='blue')  
ax.legend(loc="upper left")
ax.set_xlim(-2.5, 1.5)

fig.savefig('graph3', dpi=600, bbox_inches='tight')  # save thhe image
```

And I get the same error: **raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Failed to process string with tex because latex could not be found**

Any post, where is the answer to this question does not provide necessary information.

So, I have installed LaTex (MikTex) and a try

```
pip install latex
```

but it's not working. *Maybe there are other ways to solve this problem?* So, if I use the example from [matplotlib docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/tex_demo.html), I get the not quite correct display of formulas:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

While everything below this is true, a stand-alone installation of miktex will fix this problem for a conda-installed python. After installation, open the miktek console and scroll the package list to cm-super; left-click to install. The next time you try to python tex_demo, python will open miktex. Just keep installing its demands until they stop and then tex_demo will run correctly. I simply did not believe python would require a stand-alone tex installation to function correctly nor that it would "find" such an installation. I was wrong.

I have a system that has both an anaconda installation and a wsl2 ubuntu where I can fix this. I think this has existed for a while; namely, the tex_demo.py [.ipynb] if downloaded will not run correctly on a conda installation. On the ubuntu that is side-by-side in windows wsl it also crashed originally. A fix found on the web is to install cm-user (sudo apt install cm-user) Then both work as they should. The problem on the windows side is that the cm-super package is not available via conda or pip. If there are other solutions, they are ugly and involve installing tex/latex. The ipynb version will run with either the Ip or sage kernel. Sorry to be the bearer of bad tidings. Should be easy to fix as Ubuntu has already done so, but I have not found any way to even request the addition of this package in Windows. My systems where this is true are python 3.9 and 3.10. I have not tried the Microsoft Store python installation.

I was asked to clarify the answer above. What follows is my attempt to re-create the motivation for the above.
At matplotlib.org one can find and download tex_demo.py;e.g.,
https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/tex_demo.html offers downloads at the bottom of the
page. I will stick with  the .py file to make these points. This is an up-to-date windows 10 desktop.
I have uses python on it for some years.
By python here I mean an anaconda distribution downloaded and used pretty much straight as is. Now it is:
(base) PyPortfolia >>python -V =>> Python 3.10.10. I suspect the failure has existed for a long time on windows/anaconda installations.

I captured the screen of errors and I will provide if asked. My experience is that one can change the .py file a bit and change the
errors, get a partial rendering with different errors, but never fix it. The motivation for this statement is that I have fixed it.
Recently I decided I wanted to install sagemath and to do so requires installation of wsl (Windows Subsystem for Linux"). This
turns out to be quite lovely in its latest version, wsl2. I then chose Ubuntu 22.04 for the linux and installed it. Matplotlib says
rendering latex requires cm-super; https://matplotlib.org/stable/devel/dependencies.html. I can open Ubuntu in a windows terminal:
uname -a => Linux DT-9010 5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Fri Jan 27 02:56:13 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux;
python -V => Python 3.10.6. The tex_demo.py failed in much the same way as with conda python. I pasted the error and found I needed
cm-user which is available under apt in Ubuntu; apt list |grep cm-user =>
cm-super-minimal/jammy,now 0.3.4-17 all [installed,automatic]; cm-super-x11/jammy 0.3.4-17 all;
cm-super/jammy,now 0.3.4-17 all [installed]. After that tex_demo.py works perfectly, just as Matplotlib.org shows it.

One thing that is a bit confusing is that anaconda has some latex built in. I have been using things like alpha and
beta in plot labels for years conda python. I am not sure where the capability comes from; I don't think it is anything
I import. I suspect it is built into the anaconda base. So, at a certain level of simplicity latex does get rendered in
conda python. But lots of symbols and structures are not there and invoking these will cause a crash.

The package cm-user is available in Ubuntu and the tex_demo.py works. The package is not available in conda or pip and thus
tex_demo will crash on a windows installation. I sure hope this is now clear. wsl2 is a great feature for windows, particularly
if you also install windows terminal (wt.exe).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).